# How to prove this inequaliy $(a+b)^3+(b+c)^3+(c+d)^3+(d+a)^3\ge 8(a^2b+b^2c+c^2d+d^2a)$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c,d>0$,show that
$$(a+b)^3+(b+c)^3+(c+d)^3+(d+a)^3\ge 8(a^2b+b^2c+c^2d+d^2a)$$

I want use AM-GM inequality to solve it,such
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3a^2b+3ab^2$$
so we must to prove
$$2(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)+3(ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2)\ge 5(a^2b+b^2c+c^2d+d^2a)$$
Then I can't

Comment: You asked the same question last year: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259930/show-this-inequality-xy3yz3zw3wx3-ge-8x2yy2zz2ww2x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show this inequality $(x+y)^3+(y+z)^3+(z+w)^3+(w+x)^3\ge 8(x^2y+y^2z+z^2w+w^2x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259930/show-this-inequality-xy3yz3zw3wx3-ge-8x2yy2zz2ww2x)